# Magento 2 - store bank payment data

Tags: magento2, database, model, payment

We have a debit payment method where the user has to enter some data like his **name**, **IBAN**, **BIC** and **the name of the bank**.

I need to store these pieces of information in our database and automatically load them if the user visits the checkout again.

Should I create a new database for this or should I store the information in the customer model in tables like `customer_entity_varchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DON'T store data like that in your store.

Use plugins that already exist that tokenize banking data. This makes it so even if your site is compromised, your user credit card/debit card is not. Most modern payment plugins already do this - *Authorize.net / Moneris / etc*.

IF you are not afraid of being hacked, I would create a separate Table that stores that data based on User ID.

Please look into [encrypting this data](https://magecomp.com/blog/use-encryption-decryption-magento-2/) as you don't want that kind of information out there.

**PS:** Remember that Guest accounts do not have user id, so you will need to deal with those separately.

Comment: Don't worry, we use encryption to store the data and we already have the OK from our data protection agent. We don't store credit card information. We don't have guest accounts. Thx

Comment: @Black ok, then yes, you can just put that data into a separate table. No need to put it inside customer model as you want modularity - if the plugin is removed, then you can delete the table too without having to remove data from core table. (FYI: Prefix your table with the name of your company so it's clear what the table is. For example Microsoft would be mcsft_credit_cards or something like that).